# Cannot Import Firebase Into Swift Class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am totally new to Firebase and building iOS apps. In Xcode 7, I am trying to import Firebase into my Swift class. In a swift file, I have typed "import Firebase".

I am getting an error that says

> "No such module 'Firebase'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the Firebase SDK? Manual or CocoaPods?

Comment: I have been using CocoaPods. I am still having trouble even after the answer.

Comment: If you have multiple targets, make sure the pod is added to all of them. That was the mistake in my case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways to install Firebase: manually, and with CocoaPods.

I recommend using CocoaPods. In your `Podfile`, make sure you specify `use_frameworks!`:

```
platform :ios, "9.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
 pod 'Firebase'
end
```

Then after you `pod install` and open the `MyProject.xcworkspace`, you should be able to use `import Firebase`.

edit by Jay:

If you are targeting OS X your pod file may look more like this

```
platform :osx, '10.10'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
  pod 'FirebaseOSX', '>= 2.4.2'
end
```

Comment: I am still having trouble. I tried using your Podfile and I still cannot use `import Firebase`.

Comment: Can you post your Podfile?

Comment: Here is my Podfile:                                                                         `platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'The Lighthouse App 1' do
  pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.4.2'
end`

Comment: Building project solves the issue after reinstalling with new podfile.

Comment: LI Xinyang - I never thought of that! Damn. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the configuration in OSX. However, I don't know how to do the configuration in code. In iOS, we do "FirebaseApp.configure()", but not in OSX.

Comment: I found the problem. I declared the pod 'Firebase' under the Tests Target... That might be the problem for others.

Answer (score 49):

For me it was this:

The Framework is called FirebaseAnalytics now and not Firebase.

The official documentation even has this wrong.

So after installing with CocoaPods (Firebase version 3.4.0) this works:

```
import FirebaseAnalytics
```

Comment: Thanks. This did solve it for me. I was following the official one and that just wanted me to import Firebase. Upvoted

Comment: It depends on which sub-framework you are importing.  If you are using the database, it is called import Firebase

Comment: For the newest Firebase, `import FirebaseCore`

Comment: Yup can confirm it was import FirebaseCore if using the MacOS pods

Answer (score 10):

If you imported Firebase manually, update `Framework Search Paths` and `Header Search Paths` under your target's `Build Settings` so they include the Firebase frameworks.

Comment: I had to add to `Header search Paths` the path to the place where Firebase.h is. For example `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks/Firebase`

Answer (score 4):

When using the CocoaPods installation method, you can start by removing the project workspace file:
`rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace`

Then, edit the Podfile to following, which will be automatically set for the latest version of Firebase:

```
use_frameworks! 
target 'MyProject' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
end

target 'MyProjectUITests' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

Finally, reinstall the pod

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have added the firebase framework manually, delete it and add it again.Rebuild the project and it will work.

There seems to be a bug.This happens when you discard the changes.

Answer (score 2):

1. open terminal and type cd "drag and drop your project" Enter
2. type "pod init"
3. open pod file with xcode
4. under use_frameworks! type 
   pod 'Firebase'
   pod 'Firebase/xxx'
5. back to terminal and type "pod install"
   6.open your project folder and run xxx.xcworkspace

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to make sure that cocoapods was updated to version 1.0.0.

Just run `sudo gem install cocoapods`, then clean project and `pod install`. Compiler should not complain anymore.

Comment: This worked for me. Added pods to stage and test targets.

Answer (score 1):

So after spending hours and hours trying to fix this error I did the following and my life went back to normal

a) Went to my Podfile and changed  **pod 'Firebase', '~> 4.8'** to  **pod 'Firebase/Core'**

b) Then I went into my AppDdelegate 
changed from **import Firebase** to **import FirebaseCore**

If you were facing the same problem as me this solution will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Those who are using `swift 3` are welcome to try this. It worked for me.

My pod file:

```
platform :osx, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase'
end
```

AppDelegate:

```
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that I wrote the line : (pod 'Firebase') in the wrong line in the pod file. you only need to find the comment : # Pods for projectName
and then replace it with pods like: pod 'Firebase' or : pod 'Firebase/Auth'

Answer (score 0):

In your Podfile make sure to have pod 'Firebase' in addition to your pod 'Firebase/Core' [image] After, :wq from vim and run a command `pod update`. Make sure to open .xcworkspace