# Importing FirebaseAnalytics module instead of Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I was working on Google Analytics and google said that I need to install Firebase to handle Google Analytics actions.

I installed Firebase through Cocoapods and imported property list(.plist) file that firebase.google.com supplied.

But when I try to import Firebase module by `import Firebase` Xcode says there is no such module and auto-complete advises `import FirebaseAnalytics`.

If I use FirebaseAnalytics module I got the error shown below. I looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215522/cannot-import-firebase-into-swift-class) question, but none of the answers solved my problem.

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'


target 'MyApp do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for MyApp
    pod 'Firebase/Core'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning up your derived data folder. ([See this article for help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933382/6436485)) Also, removing the pod and adding it back again might help. :)

BTW: Did you implement `FIRApp.configure()` in AppDelegate.swift?

Comment: There are also multiple threads about the `linker command failed with exit code 1`.

Comment: I already tried to reinstall pods. And I implemented FIRApp.configure() only with import FirebaseAnalytics and that results linker command failed error.

Comment: See if also adding 'Firebase' to your podfile makes a difference.

Comment: I tried just using import 'Firebase', but it didn't make sense. Finally I added frameworks without using Coocapods.

Comment: Of course it works. :D Someone doesn't like cocoapods.