# I'm trying to add Firebase to my Today Extension. It won't let me import firebase into my View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

like the title says: I'm trying to add data from Firebase to my Today Extension. I've added all of the frameworks from my main project and now I'm trying to "import Firebase" into the .swift file for the today extension and it can't find it.

I'm using Swift 2.3 and the latest version of Firebase. Also, I'm very new to development so while I'm getting pretty familiar with the tools and language, I'm not entirely sure how everything connects so it's hard for me to troubleshoot. (And Google isn't pulling up anything relevant.)

I have not added the Google Info plist file to the app extension or pod files. But all of that is in the main project and working just fine.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, this isn't exactly the same but the second answer here shows 2 different targets. I'm going to try keeping the same pod file but just add another target for my today extension.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215522/cannot-import-firebase-into-swift-class

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new target to your podfile with the same name as the today extension you make.