# Trouble importing Firebase into my Swift iOS project, even after installing the pod file

Tags: firebase

I've followed the appropriate Pod instructions to install the Firebase SDK - attached is a screenshot which shows that XCode cannot find a module 'Firebase', even though the Firebase Pods have clearly been installed - I'd appreciate any help -

On a side note, I already checked out this post:
[Cannot Import Firebase Into Swift Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215522/cannot-import-firebase-into-swift-class)

I also tried rebuilding my project, but it was to no avail.

[No such module 'Firebase' (image attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR6kG.png)

Comment: Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: @TheeBen - yup.